# Double tap copy paste stopped working on Linux 5.x

Tags: linux, mouse, kernel, copy

I have upgraded my kernel from the stock 4.9.0-12amd64 to 5.6.9 and the double tap paste (when you push down both the LEFT and RIGHT mouse button on the touchpad of your laptop) stopped working in editors in my X. I would note that no packages were updated or any other configuration file changed. I'm sure it is a kernel option which is missing (hopefully this feature was not removed). Anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Your post makes no sense at all  because you have provided no context.  Is there some Linux distribution that you're using?  Otherwise there is no such thing as a *"stock"* kernel.    What kernel build configuration did this *"stock"* kernel use?  What kernel build configuration does this *"upgraded"* kernel use?  How did you perform this *"upgrade"*?

Comment: if you dont offer a solution what you come here trolling and wasting my time

Comment: Real X11 mice have three buttons, if you only have two buttons you need to enable the "Emulate3Buttons" option

Comment: @littlefox the comment you responded to asked valid questions and replying as you did is unprofessional and unkind. You need to give us information before we can answer you questions.

Answer (score 0):

OK Regarding the useless trolling answers I have resolved this issue after spending many hours trying to recompile the kernel first with the exact same mouse related options the old one had (didn't work). Then tried this:

```
#Section "InputClass"
#    Identifier "middle button emulation class"
#    MatchIsPointer "on"
#    Option "Emulate3Buttons" "on"
#EndSection
```

Then I tried to switch it to evdev based.
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev

Didn't work. Then I have removed everything related to mouse0 from the xorg.conf and added this:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "middle button"
   MatchIsPointer "on"
   MatchDriver "libinput"
   Option "MiddleEmulation" "on"
EndSection
```

And this did the trick.